# Unable to filter XML based on given conditions

Tags: perl, xml-twig

Sorry guys, I may be asking a stupid question but I am not so well-versed in Perl or for that matter in awk(shell programming).

My requirement is to filter XML based on some conditions.

For reference I am providing a dummy XML:

```
<TRADEEXT>
    <TRADE origin = "AB"  ref = "1" version = "1"/>
    <TRADE origin = "AB"  ref = "1" version = "2"/>    
    <TRADE origin = "ABC" ref = "1" version = "1"/>    
</TRADEEXT>
```

Now the filter conditions are as follows :

1. Only those TRADES must be selected which have origin = "AB"
2. After applying first condition, make sure to choose only those TRADES which have highest version based on ref(group by ref)

So the resultant XML with filtered TRADES must look like

```
<TRADEEXT>
    <TRADE origin = "AB" ref = "1" version = "2"/>    
</TRADEEXT>
```

I managed to filter the TRADES whose origin is "AB" as mentioned in below code. 
But i am not able to filter the TRADES based on highest version for a given ref.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );
$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

sub TRADE {
    my ($twig, $TRADE) = @_;
    foreach my $c ($TRADE) {
        $c->cut($TRADE) unless $c->att('origin') eq "AB";
    }
}
```

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one `TRADE` element that has the maximum value of `version` for the given origin` and `ref`? You could keep all of them, the first one that is found, or the last one that is found. Or you could say that the situation should never occur and so it's an error.

Comment: Thanks, and how big is your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest way to do this is to take two passes through the XML data: the first to find the maximum `version` for each `ref`, and the second to remove anything elements that have a version  less than the maximum.

This program uses the `TRADE` twig handler to build a hash `%max_version` of maximum versions per `ref`. It doesn't affect the parsing of the data at all.

Then a `for` loop scans through all `TRADE` children of the *root element* `TRADEEXT`, using `delete` to remove all those that have a version other than the maximum.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig 3.48;

my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    twig_handlers => { '/TRADEEXT/TRADE' => \&trade_handler },
    att_accessors => [ qw/ origin ref version / ],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my %max_version;

$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');

for my $trade ($twig->root->children('TRADE')) {
  my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);
  $trade->delete unless $version eq $max_version{$ref};
}

$twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

sub trade_handler {
  my ($twig, $trade) = @_;

  if ( $trade->origin eq 'AB' ) {

    my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);

    unless (exists $max_version{$ref} and $max_version{$ref} >= $version) {
      $max_version{$ref} = $version;
    }
  }

  1;
}
```

**output**

```
<TRADEEXT>
  <TRADE origin="AB" ref="1" version="2"/>
</TRADEEXT>
```

Comment: Hmm, good answer. I had some notion of using `cut` to save/replace highest versions, but it's hard to tell how far you've got.

Comment: @Sobrique: Rather than using `cut` on everything and then `paste` on all the elements with maximum versions, I would just keep a hash of the `TRADE` elements as they are parsed, indexed by the `ref` attribute. When a new maximum is encountered, all the old elements are removed from the hash and from the XML data using `delete`. It would be worthwhile coding it if the data were huge, but for 1GB it's best to do it the cleanest way.

Comment: Its throwing error 'Cant locate object method "origin" via package XML::Twig::Elt'...Not able to debug it ...Kindly help..

Comment: @karanarora: Do you have the `att_accessors` line in the constructor call? I added that later on.

Comment: we are running exactly the same code which is mentioned above.. But its throwing error 'invalid option 'Att_Accessors'

Comment: @karanarora: Then I should say that you need to update your copy of `XML::Twig`

Comment: And you have `att_accessors` and not `Att_Accessors` as you wrote above? What do you get if you `print $XML::Twig::VERSION`?

Comment: @karanarora: It looks like the `att_accessors` option was introduced in `XML::Twig` version 3.36.

Comment: @Borodin - your code is working amazingly but the performance is not efficient...I am trying to implement purge() and flush() in this but not working....Can you please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly - you're missing a trick.

When you use a `twig_handler` it 'snips out' a segment of XML, and passes it to the subroutine, and does that each time it encounters it.

So `$TRADE` as seen in your sub is (parsed):

```
<TRADE origin = "AB" ref = "1" version = "1"/>
```

Your `foreach` loop therefore doesn't really make any sense.

You can probably simplify to:

```
sub TRADE {
    my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
    if ( not $TRADE -> att('origin') eq 'AB' ) {
        $TRADE -> cut();
     }
}
```

Although if you're not `paste`ing, then you probably want to use `delete()` instead.

As you want to save data based on highest version, you need to inspect the whole lot before you do. One approach might be - to parse the XML twice - once to extract highest versions.

But as you're using `cut` you can perhaps use `paste`.

Comment: @sobrique--great insight..But I am really stuck at second filter condition...where I ahve to select trades based on highest version for a given ref..can you advice something for that

Comment: Well, you can save the data from your `cut`, and save it in a hash.